# Can Blender be made to indicate directly, if auto-saving is in progress?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

If Blender is unresponsive, I can only tell if that's due to auto-saving, by looking at the disk footprint in Task Manager.

This problem is giving me a headache. Is there any way to achieve an indication of auto-save status from within the application?

Comment: Hi, this is question and answer site about using Blender. For general discussion try [blenderartists forums](https://blenderartists.org/), for feature suggestions there is [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/). Opinion based questions and feature requests will get closed here. If you want a solution for a problem, maybe edit the question and form it as a question.

Comment: For the reasons given by @MartynasŽiemys, I've tried to rephrase this question to fit with BSE's remit. I hope the edit catches your meaning. The part of your post that's a feature-request to the developers, should be posted on Right-Click-Select. (Good Idea, BTW. :)  )

Comment: @Robin Betts Thanks for the review, exactly what I wanted to express, I will go to Right-Click Select to submit my thoughts, thanks again